# Making lists that fit specific characteristic from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe from which I want to create a list of names that fit a certain characteristics. For example, this is the dataframe:

```
name    age     hair color
Tim     32  black
Alex    29  red
Jerry   25  brown
Molly   30  black
Susan   27  black
```

How could I make a list of only the names that have black hair?

Comment: `df.loc[df['hair color'].eq('black'),'name'].tolist()`

Comment: `df.name[df['hair color']=='black']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering Pandas column with specific conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311599/filtering-pandas-column-with-specific-conditions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df[df['hair color']=='black']['name'].tolist()
```